# git - get commits between tags on second level (--second-parent?)

Tags: git, git-log

I try to get all commits between two tags.

If the git history is:

```
* A - 2.0
| \
|  * B
| /
* C
|
D  - 1.0
```

I can use `git log 2.0..1.0 --first-parent` to get commit A, C and D.

What would be the git command for:

```
* X - 2.0
|\
| * A
| |\
| | * B
| |/
| * C
| |
| * D
|/
* Z  - 1.0
```

To also only getting A, C and D. Everything I tried so far (min/max parents) had included commit B or excluded A, C and D.

Comment: I doubt you can, unless you can somehow formulate a programmatic rule that says "I don't want B because of .......".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for a fact that `2.0` is a merge commit, you can use `2.0^2` to say "the second parent of that merge commit" :

```
git log --first-parent 1.0..2.0^2
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about ancestry references up until now. That makes my git life so much easier!